# Help with strange relationship

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I have an object called "Comment" now a Comment can be associated with a "News" article OR a "Feature" article or a "Product". So will look something like:

```
public class Comment
{
[BelongsTo]
public Feature Feature
{get;set;}

[BelongsTo]
public News News
{get;set;}

[BelongsTo]
public Product Product
{get;set;}
}
```

Now obviously only 1 Feautre, Product, or News will be populated at a time, and all implement interface "IContent". So how do I get one property like:

```
[BelongsTo(Type = Change type at runtime!!)]
public IContent Content
{get;set;}
```

Any idea how to structure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[Any]`. Docs about this [here](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/trunk/usersguide/relations/hasmanytoany.html) and [here](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/trunk/manual/attributedocs/Generated_AnyAttribute.html).

Comment: Perfect! Any idea how to then do a News.Comments? or a Feature.Comments?

Comment: @Paul: not sure what you mean... can you elaborate in a new question?

Comment: Sure, well you can join from a Comment to a Content by "Comment.Content" where Content is either a "News", "Feature", or "Product". However if I go the other way "News.Comments", "Feature.Comments", or "Product.Comments" it would usually find the "BelongsTo" on the "Comment" side but now it only has an "Any". Does that make sense?

Comment: @Paul: on the other side of the relationship (i.e. in News, Feature, Product) you'd have a collection of Comments marked with [ManyToAny]

Comment: Thanks thats perfect! I thought it was going to be that but second guessed myself when it didn't work first off.

Comment: @Paul: actually I think I'm wrong. `[ManyToAny]` is not the inverse of `[Any]` but its equivalent for collections.

Comment: Yeah Actually I had figured that out now I really am at a loss I can't seem to figure out how to connect to the "Any". Is this possible?